# setFieldValue, Formik and InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: reactjs, forms, file, upload, formik

I'm trying to upload a file using Formik and setFieldValue.

I don't understand why i'm getting

> InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element > accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

When i'm uploading a file

I have some knowledge of React, but it's my first time with Formik.

Some (maybe useful) code

```
export const ImageUploaderField = ({ ...props }) => {
    const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext()
    const [field] = useField(props)
    return (
        <Field
            {...field}
            {...props}
            onChange={(event) => {
                setFieldValue(field.name, event.currentTarget.files)
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Call site

```
<ImageUploaderField name="filename" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 20):

I was having the same error. Got it working by adding a `value={undefined}` prop to `<input>` element.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally fixed it after struggling for a day. Can you please tell why 'value={undefined}' should be added? Thanks again!

Comment: @uitwaa I'm glad it helped you! Not 100% sure why it works, but I think that way you avoiding Formik to handle the value of that input.

Comment: Thanks @Camilo. This works! I think Formik cannot correctly control the value state of an input element for `file` type, so setting it to `undefined` helps.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding **value={undefined}**, ignore adding value property to Field

```
export const ImageUploaderField = ({ ...props }) => {
    const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext()
    const [field] = useField(props)
    const {value, ...rest} = field;
    return (
        <Field
            {...rest}
            {...props}
            onChange={(event) => {
                setFieldValue(field.name, event.currentTarget.files)
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// set value to undefined will solve your problem   
                     <TextField
                      size="small"
                      fullWidth
                      id="ticket-file"
                      type="file"
                      name="file"
                      label="Upload file"
                      value={undefined}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        setFieldValue("file", event.currentTarget.files);
                      }}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      accept="image/png, application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
                      InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                      }}
                      inputProps={{
                        multiple: true,
                      }}
                      error={touched.file && Boolean(errors.file)}
                      helperText={touched.file && errors.file}
                    />
```